# Открытие формы в левом нижнем углу

Tags: c#, форма

Как при нажатии `button`'a открыть вторую форму в нижнем левом углу. Да, можно открыть в правом верхнем углу, в центре (это все в `properties`), но вот как можно, чтобы она открылась над часами (`tree`)?

Т.е. ширина формы должна быть довольно маленькой (к примеру, `this.width = 150; this.height = 150;`) но при том открыта в нижнем левом углу, над часами.

Буду весьма благодарен.

Comment: Не забудьте, что физических экранов (мониторов) **может быть несколько** и вычислять `Width` и `Height` экрана нужно соответствующим образом.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно задать координаты Top, и Left для формы.

```
Left = Ширина экрана - ширина твоей формы 
Top = Высота экрана - высоту формы
```

Как узнать ширину и высоту экрана нагуглите =)

```
ширина формы - this.width;
высота формы - this.height;
```

можно на событие Show повесить вычисление координат.

Comment: вы меня не поняли ширина формы должна быть довольно маленькой(к примеру this.width = 150; this.height = 150;) но при том открыта в нижнем левом углу, над часами

Comment: может быть нижний ПРАВЫЙ угол?

Comment: ага, вы правы нижний ПРАВЫЙ угол !